# Trying to write a program where it searches for all individual letters of a string that are contained in a word

Tags: python

*Each line given consists of two strings. The program needs to  print True if the first string is a substring of the second (and False otherwise).
Example
Rain  Rainbow, True.
rainb  Rainbow,True.
raInbO Rainbow,True.
owa,False.
and so on*

**my code works except when the letters are capitalised , eg for "raInB" it would give false**

```
import sys


for s in sys.stdin:
    tokens = s.strip().split()
    a = tokens[0]
    b = tokens[1]

    print(a in b)
```

Comment: aib is NOT a substring of rainbow. All three letters are contained but not that pattern. You should rephrase your question to indicate you are searching if all individual letters of a string are contained in a word, and you cannot use more letters that are available in the word, e.g. “oww” would be illegal as two w’s.

Comment: my bad , yes its not i got confused. Il fix the errors now

Comment: errors are fixed , my code works except when other letters(except the first) are capitalised.

Comment: [s.lower()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)

Comment: In regards to capitalization, you should familiarize yourself with all of the python methods that work on objects with a “string” data type. One of those methods is lower(). https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/lower.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys


for s in sys.stdin:
    s=s.lower()
    tokens = s.strip().split()
    a = tokens[0]
    b = tokens[1]

    print(a in b)
```

Answer (score 0):

For all the substrings in the string, you can try this:

```py
string = "Rainbow"

def return_substrings(input_string):
    length = len(input_string)
    return [input_string[i:j + 1] for i in range(length) for j in range(i, length)] #if len(input_string[i:j + 1]) > 1

var = return_substrings('abc') #Enter the substring

for i in var:
    if i in string:
        print(i, "is in string")
```

For capitalisation, you can change the script above to `if i.lower() in string.lower()`